# iOS 8 Action Extension icon sizes

Tags: icons, ios8, xcode6, ios-app-extension

While trying to solve this [iOS 8 action extension icon is blank on device (works in simulator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733932/ios-8-action-extension-icon-is-blank-on-device-works-in-simulator) problem, I realized that nowhere are informations available what size an iOS 8 Action Extension icon must have. Also the technical requierement "PNG is recommended" and "monochromatic" are not very clear. Does anybody know where to place the icon for an Action Extension in XCode 6 and what dimensions and format it must have.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Services.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH13-SW1):

> iOS. Create a template image that represents your Action extension. A
>   template image is an image that iOS uses as a mask to create the final
>   icon that users see in the activity view controller. To create a
>   template image that looks good in the final UI, follow these
>   guidelines:
>
> Use black or white with appropriate alpha transparency. Don’t include
>   a drop shadow. Use antialiasing. Create the image in two sizes:
>
> For **iPhone**, the image should look good centered in an area that
>   measures **60 x 60 points**.
>
> For **iPad**, the image should look good centered in an area that measures
>   **76 x 76 points**.

Also, more info you can get from [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH67-SW1).

> Use a monochromatic version of the app icon for an Action extension.
>   (In contrast, a Share extension uses its containing app’s full-color
>   app icon.) To create an icon for an Action extension, you might start
>   by creating a stencil version of your app icon. If necessary, simplify
>   the design by focusing on the elements that make your icon unique.
>
> If you provide multiple Action extensions in your containing app, it
>   can work well to create a family of icons for them. Be sure to make
>   every icon in the family look related to the containing app’s icon.

**Edit:**
From [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1) (search for icon):

> In iOS, a custom Action extension uses a template image version of its
>   containing app’s icon, which you must provide.
>
> iOS Share extensions automatically employ the containing app’s icon.
>   If you provide a separate icon in your Share extension target, Xcode
>   ignores it. For all other app extension types, you must provide an
>   icon that matches the containing app’s icon.
>
> For information on how to add an icon to your app extension, see
>   [Creating an Asset Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/CreatinganImageCatalog/CreatinganImageCatalog.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH2) and [Adding an App Icon Set](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog/AddingLaunchImagestoanAssetCatalog.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH8) or Launch Image
>   Set. For more about icon requirements for iOS app extensions, see “App
>   Extensions” in iOS Human Interface Guidelines

**Edit 2:**
Create an AppIcon image asset in your extension's folder and add your icons in that set and reference that asset in your extension's and app targets.

Also make sure that your extension icon have a fully transparent background, and not a solid white. Any colour other than transparent, will be shown as solid dark grey.

[image]

Comment: ```For iPhone, the image should look good centered in an area that measures 60 x 60 points.``` this does not tell the icon dimensions :-(

Comment: 60x60 is the container area size for your icon. It's your choice whether you fill it up with content or use a smaller and centered image. I mean you can make in Photoshop a 60x60 points canvas size with a small image in the center and that's your icon.

Comment: Ok, I see. Where should I add this img? Because in the default AppIcon Asset container there is no slot prepared for a 60x60 icon!

Comment: You should use an Image Asset container instead of Icon Assets.

Comment: @powtac And actually if you create a new App Icon Asset there is a spot for 60x60 app icon! Check my second edit.

Comment: I can not add a Image Asset instead of an Icon Asset as a "App Icons Source"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61846/discussion-between-powtac-and-codefi).

Comment: The Human Interface Guidelines now suggest it be about 70x70pt. Sadly there's still no documentation on how to add this icon, so I guess it should still go in in the 60pt iPhone App slot? What do you do about the warnings with it complaining there's no 76, 83.5, and 1024pt app icons?