# How do you provide an icon for an action extension?

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension

All the extension types use the containing app's icon, with the exception of action extension. The Apple documentation says this:

> In iOS, a custom Action extension uses a template image version of its
> containing app’s icon, which you must provide.

However it does not say how you must provide the icon. It says:

> For information on how to add an icon to your app extension, see
> Creating an Asset Catalog and Adding an App Icon Set or Launch Image
> Set.

But the links to "Creating an Asset Catalog" and "Adding an App Icon" documentation are links to how to add an icon for an *app*, they don't contain a section on how to add an icon specifically for an action extension.

The extension target does not contain an app icon section in the XCode general settings (unlike an app), so its icon presumably must be added via an asset catalog. However, even after I added an app icon image set to my extension's asset catalog, the extension's icon is still not appearing.

How am I supposed to add an icon for an action extension? And if it's via its asset catalog then why is that not working when I've added an icon image set to the asset catalog?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155957/its-just-impossible-to-add-an-action-extension-icon

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to get it to work its not enough to add the assets to the asset catalog - its additionally necessary to set the Asset Catalog compiler options of Build Settings section of the extension to specify the name of the app icon set within the asset catalog:

[image]

Comment: for Xcode 15, the key has changed to "Primary App Icon Set Name" in Build Settings section of the extension.

Comment: This works! FYI: For me I also needed to delete the app on my local device and freshly install, to actually show the app icon.

Answer (score 39):

First, you need to have an asset catalog. You may already have this but if you don't, this is easy to create.

1. Click on the group that contains the extension files.
2. From the **File** menu, select **New > File...**.
3. In the iOS section, click on **Asset Catalog** and then click **Next**.

---

Second, we need to add the app icons to our project. Note that the icons ***must have a transparent background***. If you try to use icons with a solid background, iOS will not display the icon.

1. Click the **+** button and choose **App Icons & Launch Images > New iOS App Icon**.

   [image]
2. By default, Xcode will call the icon `AppIcon` but it will also warn you that this name is in use. To remove this warning, choose a different name (e.g. `AppIconExtension-iOS`).
3. Drag your icons into the 60px placeholder. You will also need 120x120 (aka @2x) and 180x180px (aka @3x) icons. You can create additional icons if you want but these are not necessary.

   [image]

---

Third, you need to tell Xcode to use the icon when building the extension.

1. In the Project Navigator, select your project at the top of the tree.
2. Select your extension as the Target and select **Build Settings**.
3. Search for **Primary App Icon Set Name** *(or **Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name** before Xcode 15)* and enter the name of your icon.

[image]

4. Build and run the extension.

Comment: The Human Interface Guidelines now suggest it be about 70x70pt. Sadly there's still no documentation on how to add this icon, so I guess it should still go in in the 60pt iPhone App slot? What do you do about the warnings with it complaining there's no 76, 83.5, and 1024pt app icons?

Comment: As of Xcode 14, you can opt to use the Single Size option (which is the default) to provide one 1024x1024 icon and avoid the warnings :)

Answer (score 9):

We need a monochromatic icon for Extension application which has exactly same dimensions & type as we set on Appicon(Only name & icon type is differ).
Firstly we need to include assets to the extension target

> Step 1:- For adding assets click on extension scheme->Build phases
>   ->Copy Bundle Resources ->Click + -> Add assets OR Just add by click on assets in your extension target membership.

refer below screen shot

[image]

[image]

> Step 2:- Now for setting up extension App icon click on Extension
>   application from targets area, Go to build settings ->Search Assets
>   catalog compiler option ->Enter your App icon name

refer below screen shot

[image: refer below screen shot]

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for action extension icons isn't particularly helpful—try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27333408/5352503), which provides a worked example, or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26018980/5352503) coupled with the discussion continued in chat.

For the icon itself, [current guidance](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/sharing-and-actions/) is as follows:

> **Use a template image for an action extension icon.** A template image uses a mask to create an icon. Use black and white with appropriate transparency and antialiasing, and don’t include a drop shadow. Template images should be centered in an area measuring about 70px by 70px.

Comment: Ah yes, the thing that got me is anything that's not transparent gets painted in the share icon.  I couldn't figure out why my icon was completely gray.

Answer (score 2):

for Xcode 14, the key has changed to `Primary App Icon Set Name` in the Build Settings section of the extension

Answer (score 1):

Got a lot of troubles trying to solve that problem but I eventually found a workaround (I don't like it, but it works):

I ended up installing the last version of **Xcode 7**.
I opened my project with Xcode 7 and then I followed the steps provided in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27333408/3844377.

Then I ran my project from **Xcode 8** and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Greater than Xcode 14, the key has changed to **Primary App Icon Set Name** in the **Build Settings** section of the **extension**

Just add a icon into the **Media assets** and change it name "AppIconExtension"(whatevery like, do not duplicate the name)

Remove your extension, Restart your iphone。Install again.

[image]