# App icon of Share extension is not updating in device even with updating app icon

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, ios-extensions, ios-icons

In my iOS application, I have a share extension. Initially we were using the different app icons. Later we changed the app icons for the application. The old icon has got replaced from everywhere, but for Share extension, it is not getting replaced with the new icon.
Following are ways we tried out but it has not getting changed:

- Delete the application and reinstalling. -- Did not work
- Removing the derived data and rebuilding the app and reinstalling -- Did not work.

If anybody has faced the same issue and have got resolved it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like its a bug of the Apple Developer Center. Your icon is tethered to the Provisioning Profile which used to sign your ShareExtension.

I resolve a problem just changing a bundle id of the ShareExtension. Go to "General -> Identity -> Bundle identifier" and just come up a different Bundle ID.

P.S. If you dont wanted to update your bundle id just try to recreate it using following scheme. Go to "Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Your AppleID -> View Details", open the context menu using the right mouse click and perform "Move To Trash" action.

Im developing on Xcode 8.2.1, iOS 10.2.

Comment: Thank you! Seems to be cached forever. I mean.. why should one un-cache the icon after uninstalling the app and rebooting?  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯